# HTML form with Ajax sending form multiple time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created a Contact Form and added few events in it using Ajax but when i submit my form it says

```
XHR finished loading: "localhost/mysite/contact-us".
XHR finished loading: "localhost/mysite/contact-us".
XHR finished loading: "localhost/mysite/contact-us".
XHR finished loading: "localhost/mysite/contact-us".
```

I have no idea why it is doing so but here is my Ajax code **[UPDATED AFTER EDIT]**

```
$("#success-alert").hide();
    $("#error-alert").hide();
    $('button').click(function(){
    $('input').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).val()){
       $("#error-alert").show();
       $("#success-alert").hide();
       return false;
}
else
{
$('document').ready(function() {
var form = $('#contact_us'); // contact form
var submit = $('button');  // submit button
var status = $('#form-status'); // alert div for show alert message

// form submit event
form.on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

$.ajax({
  url: '/contact-us', // form action url
  type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
  dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
  data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
  beforeSend: function() {
    submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
  },
  success: function(data) {
    form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
    $("#success-alert").show();
    $("#error-alert").hide();
    submit.html('Send'); // reset submit button text

  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

});
});
});
}
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
  <form method="POST" action="/contact-us"class="static-contact-us styled" data-abide id="contact_us">
    <div class="row input-row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label class="inline">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="large-9 columns">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" required>
        <small class="error">First name is required</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label class="inline">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="large-9 columns">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" required>
        <small class="error">Last name is required</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label class="inline">Phone Number</label>
      </div>
      <div class="large-9 columns">
        <input type="text" name="phone" required>
        <small class="error">Phone number is required</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label class="inline">E-Mail</label>
      </div>
      <div class="large-9 columns">
        <input type="text" name="email" required>
        <small class="error">E-Mail is required</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label class="inline">Subject</label>
      </div>
      <div class="large-9 columns">
        <input type="text" name="subject">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label class="inline">Question</label>
      </div>
      <div class="large-9 columns">
        <textarea name="question"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="large-9 columns">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="form-status">
  <div id="success-alert" data-alert class="alert-box success radius">
  Thanks for contacting us!
</div>
  <div id="error-alert" data-alert class="alert-box alert radius">
        An error occurred. Try again later.
</div>

  <div id="form-status"></div>
```

NOTE: HTML Seems fine to me but also i added the complete Ajax now. It may be problem due to if condition.

Comment: the code looks ok. can you post your html as well.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut added and also added the complete Ajax ... Check both please !!!

Comment: you have no closure for else statement.

Comment: I added it now, still the same issue.

Comment: still your curly braces and brackets are not closing properly.

Comment: also you have a return false statement outside functions.

Comment: how did you manage to make so many syntax errors at once?

Comment: Volkan ignore brackets, its copy paste error. I checked my code twice and updated here as well now. Brackets are fine.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/GT35h/5/)

It appears that you are submitting repeatedly because you are triggering the submit event within the on submit event itself.

Try the solution below, posted on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GT35h/).

It removes the form submission event from the button event and only submits once.

It still gives the expected 404 error (because the action url is not on the jsfiddle server) , which causes it to not reset the form, but thats just because its running on jsFiddle. On your server the form will reset correctly since the success event will fire.

```
$("#success-alert").hide();
$("#error-alert").hide();


jQuery(document).ready(function() {



$('button').click(function(btn,e) {
    $('input').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $("#error-alert").show();
            $("#success-alert").hide();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {

                var form = $('#contact_us'); // contact form
                var submit = $('button');  // submit button
                var status = $('#form-status'); // alert div for show alert message


                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/contact-us', // form action url
                        type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
                        dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
                        data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                            $("#success-alert").show();
                            $("#error-alert").hide();
                            submit.html('Send'); // reset submit button text

                        },
                        error: function(e) {
                            console.log(e)
                        }

                    });
     return false;
        }

    });
});

// form submit event
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // form submit event
                    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit


    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Decide if you want to send data with this solution:

```
<form method="POST" action="/contact-us">
   (...)  
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

or

```
<form id="form">
   (...)  
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

$("form").submit(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: '/contact-us', 
      type: 'POST', 
      data: form.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function(),
         (...)
      });
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how loading the data from the HTML form fixed it, or go into how you did that so that other people who may not be familiar with it can use your solution?